# MLB near perfect game

Tags: baseball, mlb, history, trivia

To throw a perfect game a pitcher would have to get 27 batters out in a row.

How many times in MLB history has a pitcher had 26 strait outs only to allow the would be final batter to reach base?

Comment: technically you wouldn't have to get 27 batters out in a row; a batter could reach base on an error (other than the pitcher's) and the pitcher could still get a perfect game

Comment: @ThomasShields Thanks for your comment. It is good to hear from you once again. I believe this may be true in regards to a pitcher throwing a no-hitter. However, it is my understanding that in order to throw an official perfect game the pitcher would have to pitch from inning 1 through at least inning 9 (facing a minimum of 27 batters) without allowing a batter to reach base. Baseball has always provided many unique situations, without doubt I may be missing or misunderstanding something. :–)

Comment: Ah, you may be right :) I'll have to check the official rules after I get out of calc class

Comment: The final batter wouldn't reach the base. If he reached the base, he would be followed by someone else, so he wouldn't be the final batter.

Comment: This is far to easily found. Not a good trivia question.

Comment: @waxeagle Ironically when reviewing questions previously posted on this site, I read a number of your questions including your highest rated question (How is offside determined in Soccer?) Based on this reading I felt this question was appropriate.

Comment: @corsiKa Not necessarily.  I can think of two ways this could happen. First, the batter could get a hit but then get thrown out trying to reach the next base, ending the game with a win for the defense.  Second, the batter could hit a walk-off homerun, ending the game with a win for the offense.  It would be great if the OP could clarify their question with a proper definition of a near perfect game.

Comment: @Tyson Good point on the second option (home-run). I believe it would still be considered a perfect game if the runner was tagged out between first and second, though. Getting to first, rounding toward second, and getting out I do not believe counts as reaching base. I may be mistaken in this.

Comment: @corsiKa As long as the runner reaches first base safely, it would no longer constitute a perfect game (would still be a no-hitter in an error occured) regardless of whether he gets tagged out in between first and second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_perfect_games#Perfect_games_spoiled_by_the_27th_batter), this has happened 13 times. The earliest on July 4, 1908 and the most recent on June 20, 2015.